# Collect digits from a string by regular expression using split method

Tags: javascript, regex

I like to collect digits into an array from a string. I tried following way but not getting an expected result in Javascript. How can I do this?

```
'This is string 9, that con 9 some 12, number rally awesome 8'.split(/[^\d+]/);
```

Comment: What is your hosting language for regex? This does not look like anything related to `NSRegularExpression`

Comment: the `+` is not a character you want to match, i guess, try `/[^\d]+/` (but you'll have an empty first array element, and also the last one if you put text after the 8)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yes, It is my mistake. It should be /[^\d]+/

Comment: Why don't you just use `\d+`? It'll get you all the numbers

Comment: @ctwheels  Actually wanted to do this by JavaScript split method.

Comment: @webHasan is there a reason why? I mean, just doing a match on the numbers would be much more effective and likely faster.

Comment: @ctwheels match method is a perfect way, I am learning JavaScript and just tried to accomplish it by split method.  I did not get the expected result that's why from my curiosity I posted the question.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this is JavaScript not Swift.

```
'This is string 9, that con 9 some 12, number rally awesome 8 extra'.
split(/[^\d]+/);
```

produces

```
[ '', '9', '9', '12', '8', '' ]
```

As you can see, it gets you most of the way there, however there is a possible leading and possible trailing empty string.

Filter can solve this problem.

```
'This is string 9, that con 9 some 12, number rally awesome 8 extra'.
split(/[^\d]+/).
filter(function(number) { return number.length > 0 });
```

produces the answer you are looking for.

```
[ '9', '9', '12', '8' ]
```

Or if you are using ES6.

```
'This is string 9, that con 9 some 12, number rally awesome 8 extra'.
split(/[^\d]+/).
filter(number => number.length > 0);
```